# Facebook php sdk works on localhost but not on another server

Tags: php, facebook, magento

So, i know there are lot of similar topics, i've read the majority of them and still couldn't find the answer.
Here is the problem: I used facebook PHP SDK authorization on localhost, and it worked perfectly fine. getUser() function returned the id, and I could retrieve the user info. Then I moved to an actual domain, copied the working code, eddited facebook app settings, edited redirect_uri in the parameters array for getLoginUrl() function. And now I am still able to log in via this app, i get asked for the permission to access my data, but getUser() returns 0.
I am running it on magento, here is the code:

```
public function facebook_main($controller_name) {
    $appid = $this -> getAppId();
    $secretid = $this -> getSecretId();
    $facebook = $this -> facebook_config($appid, $secretid);
    $user = $this -> get_user($facebook);
    if (!$user) {
        return $this -> get_login_url($facebook, $controller_name);
    } else {
        $user_profile = $facebook->api('/me','GET');
        $facebook -> destroySession();
        return $user_profile;
    }
}

function getAppId() {
    return Mage::getStoreConfig('social/fb/appid');
}

function getSecretId() {
    return Mage::getStoreConfig('social/fb/secretid');
}

function get_user($facebook) {
    return $facebook -> getUser();
}

function facebook_config($appid, $secretid) {
    require_once "fb_include/facebook.php";
    $facebook = new Facebook( array('appId' => $appid, 'secret' => $secretid, 'cookie' => true));
    return $facebook;
}

function get_login_url($facebook, $controller_name) {
    $redirect_uri = Mage::getBaseUrl(Mage_Core_Model_Store::URL_TYPE_WEB);
    $scope = $this -> set_scope();
    $params = array('scope' => $scope, 'redirect_uri' => $redirect_uri . "/index.php/socialintegration/".$controller_name."/fb");
    $loginUrl = $facebook -> getLoginUrl($params);
    $img_url = $redirect_uri."app/code/community/Cheesecake/SocialIntegration/Model/button_images/fb.png";
    return "<a href=" . $loginUrl . "><img src=".$img_url." style='width: 40px'></a>";
}

function set_scope() {
    return 'email,user_about_me, read_stream, friends_likes';
}
```

Comment: post your code so we can see what is wrong

Comment: updated my question with code included

Comment: what is actually weird is that the same code works fine on different server with different domain. Can't figure out what could be the problem